# Regarding the range() value in Python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and am learning Python via Udemy's complete python bootcamp course.

I was working on a project given in the course of making a Tic-Tac-Toe game and got confused.

```
import random2
def choose_first():
    if random2.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'Player 2'
    else:
        return 'Player 1'
```

in the above code `random2.randint(0, 1)` is for commanding python to choose a random value between the `range (0,1)` but shouldn't the range mentioned in the code be between `0` and `0`? since the `1` represents up to the given range, meaning taking numbers before this digit but the code works fine and the value of `0` and `1` is generated.

Why is that? What am i not understanding?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use random2 instead of random? In which case the definition is [`a <= N <= b`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint).

Comment: documentation for Python 2 [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) : *"Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b."*

Comment: random.randint(a, b) is for choosing a random integer between values a and b, random.range() doesnt work to choose between floating point a and b, random.uniform(a, b)